# Enhancing the Drag and Drop User Experience for Greater Visibility During Dragging

Tags: genexus

I have a **GeneXus 18 Web** application that requires implementing a drag-and-drop feature for a CARD element, with the drop target being another object. This is explained in detail in the article Developing Drag and Drop in Web Panels.

While the functionality works as expected, I aim to improve the visual feedback provided during the drag operation. Currently, it displays text that represents the content being moved. However, I'm interested in offering a more visually striking indicator to make it abundantly clear to the user what exactly is being dragged.

Is this something that can be addressed using a Design System?

Specifically, I'd like to display a CARD that is slightly rotated and features a distinct color, ensuring that the user is fully aware of the item they are moving.